# mysqldump.exe - how to have database renamed in the dump file

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a simple utility of merging few database dump files into a single one. I have a temporary database (lets name it 'db_temporary') and have to export it into the dump but in the dump file it should be named 'db_final'. Can I do this using 'mysqldump.exe'? This seems like a trivial task but I can't find any clue in the 'mysqldump' documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysqldump.html
Big thanks to any help.

Answer (score 0):

The Dump does not contain the database name, the dump only contains the tables and data from the database youve dumped. So yes, you could import the resulting SQL code in any Database you wish, just create a database and import the SQL code into that.

At least if you use it this form:

```
mysqldump.exe -u USERNAME -p database > database_dump.sql
```

Comment: That actually depends on the options used.

Comment: Of course I can import dump to any database but the utility I'm working on is only intended to create dump files. User will import them himself. It is probably true that database name can be not included into dump files but both MySQL Admin and MySQL Workbench are writing database name into the dump file. For example: CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `db_merge`; or USE `db_merge`; I have to create similar dump files but with ability to change database name in these statements above.